# Querying a numpy array with an N-dimentional index list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a array of data, is there a way of querying the data via an N-dimentional index list?

example:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[-14., 2.,  19.],
                 [-13., 1.,  20.],
                 [-15., 2.,  18.],
                 [-13., 0.,  19.],
                 [-15., 1.,  19.],
                 [-14., 0.,  19.],
                 [-14., 1.,  20.]])


# Uniformly shaped array: works
queries = np.array([[2, 4, 6, 0], [3, 6, 4, 5]])
print data[queries]

# Properly returns
#[[[-15.   2.  18.]
#  [-15.   1.  19.]
#  [-14.   1.  20.]
#  [-14.   2.  19.]]
#
# [[-13.   0.  19.]
#  [-14.   1.  20.]
#  [-15.   1.  19.]
#  [-14.   0.  19.]]]


# N-dimentional array fails
queries = np.array([[4, 6, 0], [3, 6, 4, 5]])
print data[queries]

# IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type #
#
# Desired result:
#[[[-15.   1.  19.]
#  [-14.   1.  20.]
#  [-14.   2.  19.]]
#
# [[-13.   0.  19.]
#  [-14.   1.  20.]
#  [-15.   1.  19.]
#  [-14.   0.  19.]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two elements in the *queries* have different lengths, so they are stored as lists instead of numpy arrays; Similarly the result will also be stored as lists internally, and there will be no advantage of using numpy array against python list any more; The best you can do probably is a normal for loop:

```
[data[query].tolist() for query in queries]

#[[[-15.0, 1.0, 19.0], 
#  [-14.0, 1.0, 20.0], 
#  [-14.0, 2.0, 19.0]],
#
# [[-13.0, 0.0, 19.0],
#  [-14.0, 1.0, 20.0],
#  [-15.0, 1.0, 19.0],
#  [-14.0, 0.0, 19.0]]]
```

Or if you want to keep the result partially as numpy array:

```
[data[query] for query in queries]

#[array([[-15.,   1.,  19.],
#        [-14.,   1.,  20.],
#        [-14.,   2.,  19.]]), array([[-13.,   0.,  19.],
#        [-14.,   1.,  20.],
#        [-15.,   1.,  19.],
#        [-14.,   0.,  19.]])]
```

Comment: Iterating over the array was my current workaround, but you're explanation as to what's going on in np.array's background was what i was confused about. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`print [data[q] for q in queries]`